# Riemann Integral of $|f| \le N(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I need help proving the following:

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and suppose $|f(x)| \le N$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove, from the definition of a Riemann integral, that

$\int_a^b |f| \le N(b-a) $.

Here is my attempt at the proof, I feel like I am close, but can't see where to go from here (if I went it the correct direction to start with that is):

Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $|f(x)|\le N, \forall x \in [a,b]$.

Then $-N \le f(x) \le N, \forall x \in [a,b]$.

So $-N(b-a) \le L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P) \le N(b-a)$.

Now since $f$ is Riemann integrable, by definition, $\int_a^b f = L(f,P)=U(f,P)$.

So  $-N(b-a) \le \int_a^b f \le N(b-a)$

$\implies |\int_a^b f| \le N(b-a)$.

I can't seem to get any further from here.

**Edit:** The definition I'm using is that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if $U(f,P)=L(f,P)$ where $$U(f,P)= \sum_{i=0}^n=M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ and $$L(f,P)= \sum_{i=0}^n=m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

Thanks.

Comment: What definition of Riemann integral you know ?

Comment: If you know that $|f|\leq g$ implies that $\int_a^b |f|\leq \int_a^b g$, then put $g=N$.

Comment: The "more detail" you should give is the work you have done on the problem, just where you are stuck, and your own thoughts. This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have done significant work on the problem. For example, what definition of Riemann integral you know?

Comment: For instance, what can you say about any lower Riemann sum for $\lvert f\rvert$?

Comment: @user315916 You seem to accidentally have created a new account when registering. You should try to [merge your accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), then you will be able to edit your question and comment in the thread.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli 
Is the lower Riemann sum for $|f|$ always 0?

Comment: If $f\ne 0$ and $\lvert f\rvert$ is Riemann-integrable, no.

Answer (score 2):

For any partition $\;P=\{x_0:=a\,,\,x_1\,...\,x_n=b\;$ of $\;[a,b]\;$ , you have that for any $\;c_i\in[x_i,\,x_{i+1}]\;$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(c_i)|(x_{i+1}-x_i)\le N\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=N(b-a)$$